# Does dropout have any benefits when overfitting isn't a concern?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dropout, transformers

I'm training a transformer based deep learning model in a regime where overfitting isn't a concern. Infinite training samples are generated on demand and never repeated, so there is no training dataset to overfit on. I've confirmed experimentally that performance on a fixed validation dataset is no worse than training performance.

Is there any potential/likely benefit to including dropout in this model? Is there anything to support it resulting in better trained performance when overfitting isn't a concern?

I've tried some basic experiments and found that dropout leads to dramatically reduced performance in the early stages of training, but I haven't let it run for very long.

Comment: The fact that each training sample is not repeated, doesn't mean you could not overfit on them. And are you really confident that your check with a single "fixed validation dataset" covers all your future generalization requirements?

Comment: @frank Yes. Training samples are generated from a uniform distribution over all possible valid inputs, and that is exactly what I want to optimise the model for.  The validation set that I have is also from this same distribution. If I ever wanted to get more specific than that I would do a fine tuning step at a later date.

The premise of this question is that overfitting is not a concern. The question is whether dropout may still have other benefits.

Answer (score 4):

Even if overfitting is not a concern, dropout could still help. Neural networks are (most of the time) trained with backpropagation, i.e. stochastic gradient descent (SGD). And it is known that the stochastic aspect of SGD often helps it to escape local minima. While the main source of stochasticity is the random blocks in each epoch (with the blocks much smaller than the total dataset), techniques like dropout (might) add a different type of stochasticity that could perhaps improve your results.

So, while you can never be certain of anything with DNNs, I would definitely give dropout a try.

Comment: This is a fair point, but I'm particularly interested in whether there's any empirical evidence suggesting that it's worth trying. I'm working with limited resources and can't justify trying long training runs with it on a weak hypothesis like this, but if there are papers or practical experience showing that it can be significantly beneficial in this case then I'll give it a go.

Comment: I am not aware of any such paper showing significant benefits, and it would also surprise me a bit. Furthermore, you say you are using transformers i.e., some pre-designed architecture that others have probably put a lot of afford into optimizing. So I would not mess with this design unless I have a lot of time and money that I can spend optimizing it for my special purposes.

Comment: Transformers generally use dropout, so I'm actually going against the norm by setting it to zero. That's part of what prompted my curiosity on this. I think it's the right call for my particular use case, but there's a lot of black magic and best practice based on empirical results that goes into training transformers, so there's a chance that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation of dropout is that you can analog it as an ensemble of many neural nets.
When training, each node in the networks has some probability to be dropped.
This means that in every training step, the network architectures are different.
And when testing, we weightedl combined many networks together into a single one.

However, in training, the dropped networks' capabiliteis are less capatible then the full networks.
Thus the performance of the ensembled one might still not outperforme the full one without dropout in training.